# I have mutiple folders I want to include in doxywizard

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have mutiple folders I want to include in doxywizard. Any Idea how can I do that? Currently If I select folder with multiple subfolder in it and when I run doxygen, It is not showing me any output.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you have a look at the `RECURSIVE` flag?

Comment: No I didn't. But now it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When having specified just folders in the `INPUT` tag the files here are handled but not the files in subdirectories. For the later ones one needs the `RECURSIVE` tag (from the documentation):

> RECURSIVE
>
> The RECURSIVE tag can be used to specify whether or not subdirectories should be searched for input files as well.
>
> The default value is: NO.